# How to export emission pass of one specific object?

Tags: rendering, compositing-nodes

I want to make one specific object glare in composition. But there are other objects have emission materials, too.

My question is how to export emission pass only for one specific object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check here object index:

[image]

Basically in Cycles you can do this node setup:

[image]

and if you set your pass index to 0 for your object, it will have no glare, all others will have glare.

[image]

Comment: object index is exactly what I need, big thanks!

Comment: You are welcome